# How to run on a single server with backend docker written in two different languages (Flask, Node.js)

Tags: node.js, docker, server, microservices, devops

I don't know much about devops. But I need some devops knowledge in a new project. The project will briefly include a Flask backend with Python for machine learning. There will be a Node.js backend for other api services and voice chat. Can you give me some information about how I can run these two different backends with docker on a server? Or can you suggest resources where I can learn?

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup docker containers for each service, then use [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) to orchestrate them. Finally use a web server like [nginx](https://nginx.org/en/) with its [nginx upstream module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html) to put them under the same hostname, with the appropriate url configurations.